# Scroll ListView when keyboard is hiding some of its items

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

In my application I have 5 items in `ListView` and each item has 2 `EditText` when user click on first `EditText` keyboard appears hiding rest of the items now to enter in other items  `EditText` first I have to click back button to hide keyboard and then click on next `EditText`

I want to know whether it is possible to allow scrolling when keyboard is hiding some of the `ListView`s items? So that I can check other items and decide whether to add something in it or leave it blank.

Comment: keyboard in android has a next button right? to go to the next input

Comment: `ListView` has a built-in scroll capability, It should works when some its items is hided by appearing keyborad

Comment: but its not working..

Answer (score -1):

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: `listStockCheck = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_stock_status);`

`InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`
  `mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(listStockCheck.getWindowToken(), 0);`    I did this but its not working..